# Ajax getting a value from php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to add a div to display an error message.  But instead of the correct error message I get null every time. The null is a result of

```
<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']); ?>;
```

How can I fix this? Why is it showing as null?

JavaScript:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#open").click(function(){
                $("#register").fadeIn(500);
            });
            $("#close").click(function(){
                $("#register").fadeOut(500);
            });
            $("#log").click(function(){
                username=$("#username").val();
                password=$("#password").val();
                submit=$("#log").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "",
                    data: "submit="+submit+"&username="+username+"&password="+password,
                    success: function(html) {
                        if(html==true) {

                        }
                        else {
                            $("#error-log").remove();
                            var error_msg = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']); ?>;
                            $("#s-log").append('<div id="error-log" class="err welcome dismissible">'+error_msg+'</div>');
                            <?php unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']); ?>
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

members.php:

```
<?php if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) header("Location: ../index.php"); ?>
<?php

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined


session_name('Login');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 1 week

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['FRCteam3482Remember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the FRCteam3482Remember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: ../../index.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
// Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

$err = array();
// Will hold our errors


if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
    $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

if(!count($err))
{
    $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

    // Escaping all input data

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

    if($row['usr'])
    {
        // If everything is OK login

        $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Store some data in the session

        setcookie('FRCteam3482Remember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
    }
    else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
}

if($err) {
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
    header("Location: workspace/index.php");
    echo 'true';
exit;
}
```

Comment: when you print `echo json_encode($_SESSION['ms...` ?

Comment: Its my suggest to change your query that, `WHERE usr='$_POST['username']' AND ...`
Then keeping trying to do `alert(html);` your success values in javascript.

Comment: because $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] is not defined when there is no error?

Comment: you want to get json from the server so you must use dataType : 'json' in your jQuery ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a AJAX request makes a request to a PHP page which **returns a value**.  It is often JSON but does not have to be. Here is an example.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "a request URL",
    data:{
        'POST1':var1,
        'POST2':var2
        }
    success: function(result)
        {
        //Do something based on result. If result is empty. You have a problem.
        }
});
```

Your PHP page **doesn't always return a value** so its hard to know whats going on.  Your work-around for this is to use javascript variables wich hold echoed PHP data when your page returns empty. But this won't work in your case. Echoing PHP variables into javascript might work fine on occasion to but it is not good practise.

It won't work in your case because your javascript variables are set when the page is first loaded. At this point the variable `$_SESSION['msg']['login-err']` has not been set (or might hold some irrelevant data) and this is what your javascript variables will also hold.

When you do it the way I mentioned you can also use functions like `console.log(result)` or `alert(result)` to manually look at the result of the PHP page and fix any problems.

I would suggest doing something like the following.

```
if($err) {
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    echo $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'];
}
else
    echo 'success';
}
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: "submit="+submit+"&username="+username+"&password="+password,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response=='success') {
                alert("Woo! everything went well.  What happens now?");
                //do some stuff
            }
            else {
                alert("oh no, looks like we ran into some problems.  Response is"+ response);
                $("#error-log").remove();
                var error_msg = response;
                $("#s-log").append('<div id="error-log" class="err welcome dismissible">'+error_msg+'</div>');
            }
        }
});
```

This may not necessarily work exactly as you intended but its a good start for you to build on.

Answer (score 0):

By going through the code , it seems that you are doing redirect first then sending the response.

There is something wrong in below code snippet

```
if($err) {
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
    header("Location: workspace/index.php");
    echo 'true';
exit;
}
```